# PHP call is not returning all of the values

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use some PHP to access a database I created and load it into text boxes.  Currently, the code below loads a list of text boxes and populates the 'name' field, but loads empty text boxes for all the other sections.

I have made sure that the $row['query'] parameters are correct.
Here is what I am seeing:

[image: Screenshot of HTML]

```
    $sql = "SELECT * from salesmen";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

    echo '<table border="0">';
    echo '<tr>
        <td align="center">Name</td>
        <td align="center">User ID</td>
        <td align="center">Password</td>
        <td align="center">Commission</td>
        <td align="center">Address</td>
    </tr>';

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="' .$row['name']. '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="id" value"' .$row['id']. '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="password" value"' .$row['password']. '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" naem="commission" value"' .$row['commission']. '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" name="address" value"' .$row['address']. '"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>'
```

Comment: you are missing = after value , do it just like the name line 


        echo '<td><input type="text" name="id" value"' .$row['id']. '"></td>';

Comment: That was embarrassingly obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code. It would have caught those parse errors. Including the one for `echo '</table>'` which I edited both answers for. Least, for what you posted. I take posted code literally ;-)

Comment: @user3264455 was `echo '</table>'` a bad paste and you didn't put in the missing semi-colon? there's a suggested pending edit in your OP about it to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `=` sign on all of the other 4 columns, and name was misspelled on the commission column(Thanks Fred)!

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="id" value="' .$row['id']. '"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="password" value="' .$row['password']. '"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="commission" value="' .$row['commission']. '"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="address" value="' .$row['address']. '"></td>';
```

You also missed a semi-colon for `echo '</table>'`

Answer (score 1):

why not try the right way, you are missing `=` in input after value.

You also mispelled "name" in `naem="commission"` and will fail if `$_POST['commission']` is used in a POST call. (or GET, depending on how it's used).

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="' .$row['name']. '"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="id" value="' .$row['id']. '"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="password" value="' .$row['password']. '"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="commission" value="' .$row['commission']. '"></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="address" value="' .$row['address']. '"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

You also missed a semi-colon for `echo '</table>'` unless that was just a bad paste and it is in fact part of your actual code in your originally posted question.

Comment: you missed something too

Comment: @Fred-ii- found n sorted

Comment: you should add the fact that it was mispelled ;-)

Comment: i'm too tired thinking to del the answer, already spent hours with another op sorting his problem :)